# what is wrong with this infix to postfix conversion c++ code

Tags: c++

I have this program for infix to postfix expression conversion, but it doesn't work properly.... eg. if I enter the expression `a+b+(c-d)*e` it gives the output postfix expression as `abcd-++e*` rather than `abcd-e*++`.

```
char inputexp[50], stacks[50], resultexp[50];  
int stacktop=-1, resulttop=-1;

void priority()
{
    '^'>'/'>'*'>'+'>'-';
}

void push(char a)    
{
    stacktop++;  
    stacks[stacktop]=a;
}

void pop()
{
    resulttop++;  
    resultexp[resulttop]=stacks[stacktop];
    --stacktop;
}

void input()     
{   
    cout<<"Enter the infix expression=";  
    scanf("%s", inputexp);
}

void operandadd (char a)
{
    resulttop++;
    resultexp[resulttop]=a; 
}

void operatorfound (char a)    
{
    if(stacktop==-1||stacks[stacktop]=='(')
    {
        push(a);
    }
    else
    {         
        if(a<stacks[stacktop])        
        {              
            while(stacks[stacktop]>a&&stacks[stacktop]!='(')               
            {       
                pop();             
            }       
            push(a);        
        }    
        else         
        {            
            push(a);        
        }       
    }   
}

void rightparenthesisfound (char a)    
{        
    while(stacks[stacktop]!='(')        
    {           
        pop();       
    }       
    --stacktop;    
}

void leftparenthesisfound (char a)   
{        
    push(a);   
}

void variablefound(char a)   
{      
    resulttop++;     
    resultexp[resulttop]=a;   
}

void result()   
{      
    cout<<"Postfix Expression:"<<endl;

    for(int i=0; i<strlen(resultexp); i++)       
    {            
        cout<<resultexp[i]<<endl;        
    }    
}

int main()    
{       
    input();        
    cout<<strlen(inputexp)<<endl;
    priority();

    for(int i=0; i<strlen(inputexp); i++)         
    {            
        if(inputexp[i]=='+'||inputexp[i]=='-'||inputexp[i]=='*'||inputexp[i]=='/'||inputexp[i]=='^')             
        {                 
            operatorfound(inputexp[i]);                 
            cout<<stacks<<endl;    
        }             
        else if(inputexp[i]=='(')
        {                 
           leftparenthesisfound(inputexp[i]);            
        }             
        else if(inputexp[i]==')')        
        {
           cout<<"RIGHT "<<"STACK:"<<stacks<<endl;    
           rightparenthesisfound(inputexp[i]);                
           cout<<"RIGHT PARENTHESIS FOUND:"<<" Stack: "<<stacks<<"\t"<<"Result:"<<resultexp;    
        }            
        else             
        {                 
            variablefound(inputexp[i]);                 
            cout<<"RESULT: "<<resultexp<<endl;             
        }         
    }

    if(stacktop!=-1)         
    {             
        while(stacktop!=-1)            
        {                
           pop();                
        }        
    }

    cout<<endl<<resultexp<<endl;       
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One obvious thing wrong in your code is the no-op function `priority` which is never called.

Comment: There are several things wrong with this code (enough that it's not clear how it was intended to work), so no straightforward answer would suffice, so it's not really suitable for this site. I suggest you use `std::string` instead of `char[]`, and get the code working correctly for "a*b+c" before attempting to parse parentheses.

Comment: When you used a debugger, what line was giving you trouble?

Comment: The priority function is called in the main function

Comment: And how do i get it to work...for "a*b+c" it is giving the output as abc+*.....when * is first encountered and then it is put on the stack, but when + is encountered then * is not poped from the stack onto the resultexpression...i dont know why

Comment: Also, the statement `cout<<stacks<<endl` will start at `stacks[0]` and **print every character** until it reaches a terminating nul, '\0', character; including going beyond the end of the array.  Try using `std::vector<char>` or placing a '\0' at the ending position in the array or print the characters one by one in a controlled loop.

Comment: Your code doesn't work for "a*b+c" because your operation comparison (e.g. `a<stacks[stacktop]`) doesn't work the way you think it does. More generally, you didn't test these functions before you hooked them together. You're trying to run before you can walk, and you should slow down and start with something simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function doesn't do anything:

```
void priority()
{
    '^'>'/'>'*'>'+'>'-';
}
```

Technically, it compares one character with another.  The result is never returned.  It looks more like *obfuscated code*.

Priorities can be implemented many ways, a common method is by the `if` statement order in the code.  The first `if` comparison is the highest priority, the next `else if` is the next lower priority, and so on.

Another method is to use an association.  The association contains a priority number associated with a symbol:

```
{'^', 1}
{'/', 2}
{'*', 3}
{'+', 4}
{'-', 5}
```

This can be implemented by look up table or hard coded as a `switch` statement.

By the way, you probable want the term *precedence* instead of `priority`.

Also, you should have your function return *something*, or the outside world will not know what it is doing.

**Very important:  Search the web for "infix to postfix conversion c++", and it will return many examples for you to contemplate.**

Comment: "Obfuscated"? No, obfuscated functions serve a purpose. This looks more like cargo-cult programming.

Comment: ok then after using the priority numbers, then how do i use this function in the if condition in the main function?

Comment: Try searching the web for "calculator stack precedence c++".  Do you search the web?

Comment: at last it worked, I removed that precedence function and used if else conditions instead and it's working fine now...thanx everybody for help